# SonarQube on Mac. "configuration file, wrapper.conf: No such file or directory"

Tags: macos, sonarqube

I'm trying to use SonarQube on Mac. I'm using Java 'jdk-11.0.16.jdk' as recomended by the Documentation and postgres as my server. I have included the correct file path in the wrapper.conf file for java on my machine, but the error is still showing and I'm yet to find a solution. Any ideas?

**WRAPPER.CONF**

```
# Path to JVM executable. By default it must be available in PATH.
# Can be an absolute path, for example:
#wrapper.java.command=%JAVA_HOME%/bin/java
wrapper.java.command=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.16.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java

#
# DO NOT EDIT THE FOLLOWING SECTIONS
#


#********************************************************************
# Wrapper Java
#********************************************************************
wrapper.java.additional.1=-Dsonar.wrapped=true
wrapper.java.additional.2=-Djava.awt.headless=true
# extra args needed by hazelcast
wrapper.java.additional.3=--add-exports=java.base/jdk.internal.ref=ALL-UNNAMED
wrapper.java.additional.4=--add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
wrapper.java.additional.5=--add-opens=java.base/java.nio=ALL-UNNAMED
wrapper.java.additional.6=--add-opens=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED
wrapper.java.additional.7=--add-opens=java.management/sun.management=ALL-UNNAMED
wrapper.java.additional.8=--add-opens=jdk.management/com.sun.management.internal=ALL-UNNAMED

wrapper.java.mainclass=org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp
wrapper.java.classpath.1=../../lib/sonar-application-9.5.0.56709.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.2=../../lib/jsw/wrapper-3.2.3.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.3=../../lib/sonar-shutdowner-9.5.0.56709.jar
wrapper.java.library.path.1=./lib
wrapper.app.parameter.1=org.sonar.application.App
wrapper.java.initmemory=8
wrapper.java.maxmemory=32

#********************************************************************
# Wrapper Logs
#********************************************************************

wrapper.console.format=PM
wrapper.console.loglevel=INFO
wrapper.logfile.format=M
wrapper.logfile.loglevel=INFO
wrapper.logfile.rollmode=DATE
wrapper.logfile=../../logs/sonar.YYYYMMDD.log

# Maximum size that the log file will be allowed to grow to before
#  the log is rolled. Size is specified in bytes.  The default value
#  of 0, disables log rolling.  May abbreviate with the 'k' (kb) or
#  'm' (mb) suffix.  For example: 10m = 10 megabytes.
#wrapper.logfile.maxsize=0

# Maximum number of rolled log files which will be allowed before old
#  files are deleted.  The default value of 0 implies no limit.
wrapper.logfile.maxfiles=7

# Log Level for sys/event log output.  (See docs for log levels)
wrapper.syslog.loglevel=NONE

#********************************************************************
# Wrapper Windows Properties
#********************************************************************
# Title to use when running as a console
wrapper.console.title=SonarQube

# Disallow start of multiple instances of an application at the same time on Windows
wrapper.single_invocation=true

#********************************************************************
# Wrapper Windows NT/2000/XP Service Properties
#********************************************************************
# WARNING - Do not modify any of these properties when an application
#  using this configuration file has been installed as a service.
#  Please uninstall the service before modifying this section.  The
#  service can then be reinstalled.

# Name of the service
wrapper.ntservice.name=SonarQube

# Display name of the service
wrapper.ntservice.displayname=SonarQube

# Description of the service
wrapper.ntservice.description=SonarQube

# Service dependencies.  Add dependencies as needed starting from 1
wrapper.ntservice.dependency.1=

# Mode in which the service is installed.  AUTO_START or DEMAND_START
wrapper.ntservice.starttype=AUTO_START

# Allow the service to interact with the desktop.
wrapper.ntservice.interactive=false

#********************************************************************
# Forking Properties
#********************************************************************
wrapper.disable_restarts=TRUE
wrapper.ping.timeout=0
wrapper.shutdown.timeout=0
wrapper.jvm_exit.timeout=0
```

Answer (score -1):

```
wrapper.java.command=/usr/bin/java
```

update 'wrapper.java.command' to the following location is the solution.

Comment: When answering your own question, please elaborate more than that. You have several lines of code. Does this one go somewhere there?